# Acessing files from a Server remotely

Tags: c#, remoting

As the title says, I need to access files from a server remotely. After doing this, I need to show the files in a windows file/folder Dialog style.
I need this using Remoting.
It's not that simple since I have some problems:

1. I don't have access to the client UNC sharing;
2. I don't know where the \server\xpto is physically pointed;
3. The service at the server must use the physical path.

Also, the sharing must be enabled (not always is), I'd need to prompt username/password and I'd have the network path, not the physical.

So, it's like accessing a server in a data center using the client app.

Comment: I don't know why people negativate my questions, if you can't answer, at least don't negativate it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it by a web application. Create a page on the server which can reach the local files on the server and displays a list of them on a grid. You can add some commands on the files as well. The page you created would act as a middleware to reflect the operations you want on the files.

hope it helps.